# How can I prevent Scala from satisfying this implicit's parameters with itself, even though it's a different type?

Tags: scala, shapeless

I'm trying to make a generic decoder that decodes fields differently depending on `shapeless.Tag`s declared on those fields. To that end, I had an implicit defined as follows which can turn any decoder for `B` into a decoder for `B @@ Id` (`A` is the input type).

```
  implicit def idTagDecoder[A, B](implicit dec: Lazy[Decoder[A, B]]): Decoder[A, B @@ Id] =
    dec.value.decode(a).map(tag[Id](_))
```

When I run a test and a `Decoder` produced by this is used, I get a `StackOverflowError` indicating that Scala is satisfying the `dec` parameter with the generated decoder! If I leave off the `Lazy`, that doesn't happen, but I get "diverging implicit expansion."

So, I modified the code just to make sure this is what's going on. Now, my definition looks like this.

```
  implicit def idTagDecoder[A, B](implicit dec: Lazy[Decoder[A, B]]): Decoder[A, B @@ Id] =
    new Decoder[A, B @@ Id] {
      override def decode(a: A): DecodeResult[B @@ Id] = {
        // These are different types, so the compiler shouldn't try to satisfy `dec` with `this`, but it does!
        require(dec.value != this)
        dec.value.decode(a).map(tag[Id](_))
      }
    }
```

That gives me a "requirement failed" at run-time, as expected.

The compiler knows better than this. If I try to do what it's doing explicitly to produce a `Decoder[JAny, UUID @@ Id]`, it knows it's the wrong type and fails to compile.

```
val d: Decoder[JAny, UUID @@ Id] = Id.idTagDecoder(Lazy(Id.idTagDecoder(Decoder.uuidDecoder)))
```

Is this somehow the expected behavior? If so, how should I do what I'm trying to do? If not, does anyone know how to work around this?

I tried to get a small example that demonstrates this problem to no avail. It works like I would expect on anything simpler than my use case. You can see the code and run the failing test [here](https://github.com/justinp/bateman/releases/tag/stack_overflow_question) (with `sbt test`).

I'm using shapeless 2.3.3 and scala 2.12.13.

Thanks!

---

**Update:** Given that this looks like a bug in the Scala compiler, I went ahead and tested it against Scala 2.13.5 and the problem is still there.

Comment: It's not a bug. There's an implicit conversion from T to Lazy[T] and causing your method to resolve the implicit infinite recursion, thus StackOverflowError

Comment: @texasbruce I understand that, but they aren't the same type. It's more like it's converting an `A` to a `Lazy[B]`. More precisely, it's converting a `Decoder[JAny, UUID @@ Id]` to a `Lazy[Decoder[JAny, UUID]]`.

Comment: `A @@ B` is just a type that inherits `A` and `Tagged[B]`. `UUID @@ Id` is subclass of `UUID`. When it's resolved in the implicit, it is a valid candidate

Comment: Then why does Scala refuse to compile it if I attempt to do the same thing explicitly?

Comment: Actually it works fine for me: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/tjKWIDAIRsK9aH658rDj5A It fails if you don't provide a type argument to the method because it cannot resolve Nothing.

Comment: I really appreciate you helping out with this. I've produced many smaller examples (like the one that you posted) that work the way I expect them to, but like I mentioned in the question, there's something about the full codebase that's triggering this problem and I can't figure out what it is. If you have time, try to make it work in the tests in the code base that I posted and see if you have any luck.